# convert all jquery scripts to live scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, live

I have lot of jquery scripts which dont handle elements loaded or created on the fly, of course I can convert all my scrits and add the them the .live() function. However was wondering if there is any option or trick that could automatically simulate the live function in all the scripts without modifying them one by one manually.

Thanks for the comments , live is depreciated, so I restate my question with the .on() function.

Comment: You should start by learning first, the live() method has long since been deprecated and removed, so that's not an option.

Comment: `live` is deprectaed. You need to use `on` with a delegate selector.

Comment: So can it be performed automatically? (without the on?)

Comment: simple answer is....NO, will have to convert unless you have functions set up currently to add event handlers that you can call after insertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one trick that will make all existing event handler code work with dynamically loaded elements without updating each event handler unless you want to replace some jQuery methods with methods that work differently than jQuery has documented (not recommended).  You would have to replace all jQuery event handling methods that you are currently using with methods that forced delegated event handling into them.  This would be a bad way to do this.  Not only would you be hacking jQuery into something that would be different than it is documented and opening yourself up to compatibility issues with other code, but you'd be forced into the most inefficient use of delegated event handling (which is why `.live()` was removed in the first place).  Do not do this.  Fix your code to use the proper method of delegated event handling.  It's not hard at all.

---

`.live()` has been deprecated and even removed from the latest versions of jQuery.  You should not use it.  There is a form of `.on()` that will allow you to use delegated event handling for dynamically loaded objects.  You can see how to use the proper form of `.on()` for dynamically loaded elements in this post: [jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376).

The "proper" way to use `.on()` for dynamic elements is like this:

```
$('#parent').on("click", "#child", function() {});
```

where you select the closest parent to the dynamic element that is not itself dynamically loaded and bind the event handler to that element.

---

`.live()` was removed because it put all delegated event handlers on the `document` object somewhat analogous to this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#child", function() {});
```

If, however, you used a number of delegated event handlers like this, performance could start to bog down.  That's because when you do it this way and you click anywhere in the document and that click bubbles up to the document, it has to compare every single selector in every single `.live()` event handler you had to the current clicked object.  Since selector comparisons are not always fast, this could really bog down the processing of events.

When you place the event handler on an object closer to the actual object, you end up with far event handlers there and thus far fewer selectors to compare to and processing of the events works faster.

---

Here's a reference on some differences between static event handlers and delegated event handlers and some useful notes on them: [JQuery Event Handlers - What's the "Best" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730277/jquery-event-handlers-whats-the-best-method/9730309#9730309)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer ! it fulfilled more questions I had in mind !