# Event stops working after dynamic ul li changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

***The Code:***

```
if($('.info-dropdown').length){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('li').has('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
                $(this).find('.brand-checkbox').parent().toggleClass('active');
            });
        }, 10); 
    }
```

***The Problem:*** This code detects event click on element `checkbox`.  After dynamically changing this `ul li` the event stops working.

***Note:*** These checkboxes are from `bootstrap` dropdown menu.

Comment: Why do you need to wait 0.01 seconds before adding a click handler? Are you waiting for something to [load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)?

Comment: What are these dynamic changes you are referring to? Is it possible that the element that you applied the click handler has been removed from the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind event for dynamic HTML, You can follow below code :

```
$('containerSelector').on('eventName', 'mainElementSelector'  function(e){

});
```

Realtime example

```
$("ul").on("click", "li:has(:checkbox)", function(){

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers added directly to an object are added only to that specific DOM object.  If you then add or replace more DOM objects, those DOM object won't have any of these event handlers on them.  You will have to either manually add the event handlers after you create or replace the DOM objects or you will have to switch to using delegated event handling.

Delegated event handling attaches the event handler to a common parent object (that is not replaced) and uses the fact that many events bubble up the parent chain in order to process the event from the common parent.  This allows you to freely create or replace child elements, but still have one event handler that works for all child objects.

You can read a lot more about how to do delegated event handling in these other answers:

[jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376?s=1|0.0000#8752376)

[Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409?s=3|0.0000#9814409)

[JQuery Event Handlers - What's the "Best" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730277/jquery-event-handlers-whats-the-best-method/9730309#9730309)

As illustrated in those referenced answers, the general idea is like this:

```
$("#staticParentSelector").on("click", ".selectorForDynamicChildren", function(e) {
    // event handler code here
});
```

Comment: I tried also `on` method. It does not work for me. I tried: `$('li input[type="checkbox"]').on( "click", function() {...`

Comment: @Djavad - you will have to be a lot more specific about what you tried and what didn't work because delegated event handling (done properly with `.on()` works very well for dynamically created elements).  It is the usual solution to event handlers for dynammically created elements.  The other answers I've referenced in my answer explain how to do it properly.

Comment: @Djavad `It does not work for me` doesn't really help to get what you are doing wrong. Be more specific!

Comment: @Djavad - please read the above referenced posts.  You are not using the proper form of `.on()` for delegated event handling.  That is the static form.  You must use the dynamic form.