# Onclick + set attr checked on dynamic DOM element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I already wrote some syntax and it's WORK if the element is not DOM, but when the new DOM element added by appending some html to some div, the syntax won't work to the new element.

Please look at this code, i'm confused

```
$('.undistributed-row-tr').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        if($(this).find('.undistributed-check-one').is(":checked")){
            $(this).find('.undistributed-check-one').prop('checked', false);
        }else{
            $(this).find('.undistributed-check-one').prop('checked', true);
        }
    })
})
```

I'am using Ruby on Rails and jQuery. Thank you!

For detail code and demo, please click this link:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9akuchb/2/

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What does that even mean: "if the element is not DOM" ???

Comment: i'm sorry my knowledge about DOM Element is the element which added by 'append' method or some element which stored only at jquery/javascript

Comment: I think you mean that newly appended elements don't have the necessary listener attached?

Comment: From what I understand your event listeners are not working for dynamically added content. They will most probably not if you attach these in the beginning. While adding dynamic content add event listeners to them too. Or run this function after all elements are added to DOM.

Comment: @pilchard yes, my newly appended elements not working with my current syntax

Comment: @TusharShahi yeah thats the point, but i dont know how to 'add event listeners to them too'

Comment: The most robust solution will be event delegation, some discussion here: [Behavior #2: Dynamic or Delegated Event Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730309/13762301)

Comment: sir i'm sorry, i've add my app demo here https://jsfiddle.net/L9akuchb/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No need to use each
2. Make sure to [delegate if dynamically added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) - here I delegate from the table, assuming it is static and its ID is tableID
3. You cannot toggle the checkbox from the row if the checkbox is clicked

```js
$('#undist').on('click', '.undistributed-row-tr', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('[type=checkbox]')) return;
  const $chk = $(this).closest('tr').find('.undistributed-check-one');
  const checked = $chk.prop('checked')
  $chk.prop('checked', !checked)
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cyu467d1/

```js
$('#undist').on('click', '.undistributed-row-tr', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('[type=checkbox]')) return;
  const $chk = $(this).closest('tr').find('.undistributed-check-one');
  const checked = $chk.prop('checked')
  $chk.prop('checked', !checked)
});
$('#undist').on('click', function() {
  const len = $('.undistributed-check-one:checked').length;
  $('#move-to-distributed').prop('disabled', len === 0)
});

$('#dist').on('click', '.distributed-row-tr', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('[type=checkbox]')) return;
  const $chk = $(this).closest('tr').find('.distributed-check-one');
  const checked = $chk.prop('checked')
  $chk.prop('checked', !checked)

});
$('#dist').on('click', function() {
  const len = $('.distributed-check-one:checked').length;
  $('#move-to-undistributed').prop('disabled', len === 0)
});

$('#undistributed-check-all').on('change', function() {
  $('.undistributed-check-one').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
$('#distributed-check-all').on('change', function() {
  $('.distributed-check-one').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('#move-to-undistributed').on('click', function() {
  $('.distributed-row-tr').find(':checked').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').appendTo('.undistributed-table-body')
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="pt-6">
  <!-- card -->
  <div class="bg-white px-6 py-6 rounded-md shadow w-full inline-flex mt-4 font-poppins">
    <div class="flex w-full space-x-2">
      <div class="w-4/5">
        <table id="undist" class="st-table w-full">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left font-bold rounded-tl-lg">
                <input id="undistributed-check-all" type="checkbox" class="cursor-pointer rounded">
              </th>
              <th class="pl-0 text-left font-bold">STUDENT ID</th>
              <th class="pl-0 text-left font-bold rounded-tr-lg">NAME</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="undistributed-table-body">
            <tr class="undistributed-row-tr bg-gray-50 hover:st-bg-color-secondary-i hover:text-white p-0 cursor-pointer">
              <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" class="undistributed-check-one cursor-pointer rounded" value="1">
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 font-bold p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-28" value="IIECRI-B2-0000" readonly>
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-full" value="MUHAMMAD ROBBI ZsadadsaULFIKAR" readonly tooltip="a">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="undistributed-row-tr bg-gray-50 hover:st-bg-color-secondary-i hover:text-white p-0 cursor-pointer">
              <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" class="undistributed-check-one cursor-pointer rounded" value="1">
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 font-bold p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-28" value="IIECRI-B2-0000" readonly>
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-full" value="MUHAMMAD ROBBI ZsadadsaULFIKAR" readonly tooltip="a">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="w-1/5">
        <div class="space-y-2">
          <div>
            <button id="move-to-undistributed" class='st-bg-color-primary hover:st-bg-color-secondary focus:outline-none transition duration-300 text-4xl cursor-pointer text-white w-full rounded-md shadow font-light disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50'
              disabled>
                           &lt;
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="w-4/5">
        <table id="dist" class="st-table w-full">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left rounded-tl-lg">
                <input id="distributed-check-all" type="checkbox" class="cursor-pointer rounded">
              </th>
              <th class="pl-0 text-left font-bold">STUDENT ID</th>
              <th class="pl-0 text-left font-bold rounded-tr-lg">NAME</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="distributed-table-body">
            <tr class="distributed-row-tr bg-gray-50 hover:st-bg-color-secondary-i hover:text-white p-0 cursor-pointer">
              <td class="">
                <input class="distributed-check-one cursor-pointer rounded" type="checkbox" name="" value="1">
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 font-bold p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-28" value="IIECRI-B2-0000" readonly>
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0 ">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-full" value="MUHAMMAD ROBBI ZsadadsaULFIKAR" readonly tooltip="a">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="distributed-row-tr bg-gray-50 hover:st-bg-color-secondary-i hover:text-white p-0 cursor-pointer">
              <td class="">
                <input class="distributed-check-one cursor-pointer rounded" type="checkbox" name="" value="1">
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 font-bold p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-28" value="IIECRI-B2-0000" readonly>
              </td>
              <td class="pl-0 ">
                <input type="text" class="border-0 p-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer focus:ring-0 text-sm w-full" value="MUHAMMAD ROBBI ZsadadsaULFIKAR" readonly tooltip="a">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wait sir i'll try it first

Comment: change #tableId to the ID of a static container of the rows in question

Comment: still doesn't work sir, i'm sorry before, here  i've add my app demo at https://jsfiddle.net/L9akuchb/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cyu467d1/

Comment: @mrobbizulfikar see update